# Vue + Firebase hosting page shows blank after user logged in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, firebase-hosting

I deployed a Vue2 project to Firebase hosting server, it requires user to login to see the other pages. Currently, the site only shows login page, if the user is authenticated, it will redirect to next page, but it shows as blank.

Here is the **firebase.json** looks like

```
{
"database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 9001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 9002
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9003
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 9004
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 9005
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9006
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 9007
    }
  },
  "remoteconfig": {},
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

It did deployed to the server, but it only shows the login page. All the other pages is not showing after login (redirect from login page). It did change the path (url) correctly tho.

Here is my **route.js**

```
import Login from './components/Login'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard'
import Recipe from './views/Recipe'
import Permissions from './views/Permissions'
import Report from './views/Report'

export const routes = [{
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/login'
   },{
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login
   },{
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      redirect: '/dashboard',
      component: Home,
      children:[{
         path: '/dashboard',
         name: 'dashboard',
         component: Dashboard
      },{
         path:'/recipe',
         name:'recipe',
         component: Recipe
      },{
         path:'/permissions',
         name:'permissions',
         component: Permissions
      },{
         path:'/report',
         name:'report',
         component: Report
      }],
      meta: {
         requiresAuth: true
      }
   }
];
```

And **main.js**

```
...
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('login');
  else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('home');
  else next();
});

let app = '';
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  store.commit('authStateChanged', user);
  if(!app){
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      firebase,
      i18n,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
});
```

And the **login vue**

```
...
<script>
  import {auth} from '../fire';
  import Vue from 'vue';

  export default {
    name: 'Login',
    methods: {
      async onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.email, this.form.password)
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.replace('dashboard');
        }).catch((error) => {
          this.msg.err = error.code.replace('auth/','').split('-').join(' ');
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I deployed the app by running **npm run build** then **firebase deploy --only hosting**

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Here is the **folder structure** looks like

```
hq
    dist
        css
        img
        js
        index.html
        ...
    public
        img
        index.html
        ...
    src
        assets
        components
        locales
        views
        ...
    firebase.json
    pacjage.json
    ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if its the issue, but a wildcard route should always be the last entry of your routes. Could well be that because it's at the top, all routes, including those that are defined, now redirect to /login.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the advice, I put it to the last, unfortunately still not working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out is one of the library has issue after built, removed it and problem solved.